# Storing result of COUNT() Query into a C++ integer in SQLite

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

Can anybody tell me whether it is possible to store the result of the `COUNT()` function as an integer in C++?

Here is my code:

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    int i;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    char *sql;
    const char* data = "Callback function called";

    /* Open database */
    rc = sqlite3_open("spam.db", &db);
    if (rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        exit(0);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }

    /* Create SQL statement */
    sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST";

    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this it returns the total number of rows in the queried table – great! However, would it be possible to store the value of `COUNT()` in a variable that I could use later when I extend the function to compare to another integer?

Comment: Are you asking how to store a value in a variable? What does the callback currently do?

Comment: @CL. I've updated the code to show the static callback integer above main(). When this statement "sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST";" is run it prints the number of rows (22,000) to the console. Would it be possible to store this as int variable within my program? Thanks

Comment: Instead of printing the value, just convert it into a number. What particular problem do you have with that?

Comment: @CL. That is what I'm trying to do but unfortunately I don't know how to convert into into a number. Could you please assist? Thanks

Comment: @TheBlueNile String to number is performed by `sscanf(string, "%d", &integer)` or `integer = atoi(string);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the `data` argument to your callback point at the location where you want to store the result and extract the first column of the first row in the result passed to the callback function into this `int`:

```
extern "C" int callback(void* data, int count, char** rows,char**)
{
    if (count == 1 && rows) {
        *static_cast<int*>(data) = atoi(rows[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
// ...
int count = 0;
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, &count, &zErrMsg);
// ...
std::cout << "count=" << count << '\n';
```